# How to print Fibonacci Series and stop before stack overflow occurs - JAVA

Tags: java

I have been asked the above question / task in an job interview.

Is there any way to stop the series just before overflow occurs?

At first its seemed weird to me, i couldn't see a way where someone can predict

when is going to take place, but then my thought was to check if the current

value < Integer.MAX_VALUE.

What do you think? can anyone suggest a solution to my question?

Comment: You could use an iterative approach to avoid the possibility of a stack overflow.

Comment: See [How to understand GCInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041332/a-useful-metric-for-determining-when-the-jvm-is-about-to-get-into-memory-gc-trou) to get info about the garbage collector. For when you really need to allocate much memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your logic for Fibonacci series and add a condition before storing the value which will check free memory using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

Once free memory reaches to zero break the loop.
This should solve your overflowing issue

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a much more theoretical question rather than one with actual solution.

Lets define the Fib method to be:

```
public static int fib(n){
    if (n<=2)
        return 1;
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
```

Now by calling fib for n=100 for example, could resolve in a stack over flow exception.
If some how we simplify the way the stack works we could actually ask the function to check the "space" left in stack and hold to it's value if it's equivalent to 0.

Hope it helps!